# What happens to Laravel Faker data on teardown or end of testing

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

I am wanting to write an end to end tests that at some stage through the process will search for a model with a certain id and will update some of the data against it. To avoid touching any real data when run on production environments I know we can use Laravel Faker to create fake instances of a model and then run opperations on it, i.e.

At the start of the test I could run:

```
$someModel = factory(SomeModel::class)->create();
```

Which from my understanding will create an instance in the database with its own unique id. Once I have finished with the test I have two questions about thaat instance in question...

1. Does the entry still persist or is it auto deleted by design when using parent::teardown() or something of the like?
2. If I have to manually delete it, will there be a skipped entry in the ids as say the instance I have created which was assigned id 20 no longer exists so anyone looking at the table weill see ids: ...18, 19, 21 ... and so on?

To me I am not quite sure if its ok to have dummy data being persisted in production databases or not, is this perfectly fine?

Comment: Did you run the test then look?

Comment: Am yet to do it, just a thought, cant seem to find much about the after effects

Comment: Don't run tests on your production server. If you must, don't run tests in your production database. Tests are all run inside a transaction that's rolled back at the end but you still don't want to take that risk.

Comment: Yeah thats exctly what my colleague told me today, thanks for confirming! Never really ever thought about ci with production in mind

Answer (score 0):

To re-itterate what @miken32 said, try to avoid running tests on production, but if it ,ust be done use transactions to make sure nothing is persisted from the tests.